# VueJS v-validate methods inoperable after passing into component

Tags: vue.js

**Clearer question:**
How do I get the methods attached to the errors object to work inside a component v-validate is operating on?

**Longer question:**

I have v-validate set up to work on a component that contains an input.

It actually works well, except that the `errors` object inside the component doesn't quite operate correctly. Whenever the `errors` object in the parent is changed, I can see it reflected in the `errors.items` property - all of the errors from my form are present. But the methods are not working - `this.errors.count()` always returns zero, `this.errors.collect(this.name)` always returns an empty array.

The name property on the `this.errors.list` object matches `this.name` in the component. Even using a hard-coded string instead of `this.name` does not have an effect.

My thought is there is some sort of internal reference keeping hold of the methods, something to do with VueJS props maybe?

**Short version of code:**

```
<myinput v-validate="'required'" v-model="name" :name="name"></myinput>

<template>
    <div>
        <input
            :value="value"
            @input="updateValue()"
            ref="input"                
            :name="name"
            type="text"
            />
        <p v-for="error in errorMessages" :key="error.zerp">{{ error }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

props: [
    "name", 
    "value",        
],
computed: {
    errorMessages : function(){
        //this.errors.list has the errors
        //collect function always returns empty array []
        console.log(this.errors, this.error.collect(this.name));

        return this.errors ? this.errors.collect(this.name) : [];
    }
}
```

**More info:**
Watching the `ErrorBag.prototype.collect` method in the debugger, this.items does indeed have the collection I expect to see. I've yet to figure out how it's **not** getting the correct final collection from the name, which I can also see in the `field` property correctly.

Comment: how are you passing the "errors" to your child component?

Comment: @men32z It took me a minute to figure that out - and I'm still not entire certain. If I create a prop called "errors" it complains about a prop that's already set. I believe the v-validate plugin is hooking the errors object onto the component directly. It's worth noting that in my scenario, I have several instances of this component - and each one gets the full object of all of the errors for the entire set, hence the need to use the `collect()` method

Comment: ok, maybe could be that you are using your v-validate="'required'", outside of your child component, try passing the "required" as a prop and usign v-validate in your child component.

Answer (score 1):

You should inject your validator into your child component. No need for prop or passing errors.

```
<script>
export default {

    name: "field",

    inject: {
        $validator: '$validator'
    },

}
<script>
```

Comment: This looks like it might do it, but could you provide a more complete example of this pattern? I've yet to figure it out based on the core docs. Thanks